# Aurelia + Typescript: Pass content of one html element to another page to be added under a div

Tags: typescript, aurelia

**Requirement:** the content of a dynamically generated Table to be able to be saved as a csv. 
**Complexity:** The table contains 4 layers of nested tables all fetched dynamically  and each nested table is a new template.
**My Approach:** 
 - On the div which contains the Tables I added a ref element and bound it to a typescript variable;
 - At the bottom of the template I added a image button which calls a method of its view-model.

- The method gets the innerHTML of the referenced div and passes it to a page as string.
- The page adds the passed content (HTML String) to a div.
- The content disposition of the page is changed so that it prompts the user to save it as a Csv file.

  **Problem:** How to pass the content to another page and does the page receive and put it inside the div..

---

Even tho I haven't yet wrote it completely, I am adding little code snippet/pseudo code

---

```
<abcd.html>

<div id="tableContainer">
<table border="1" id="outerMostTable">
  <tr>
     <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
     <td>
             <!-- Inner table rendered thru a different template-->
            <table border="1" id="InnerTableLevel1">
             <tr>
                <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
                <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
                <td>
                      <!-- Inner table rendered thru a different template-->
                      <table border="1" id="InnerTableLevel2">
                         <tr>
                            <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
                            <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                            <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
                            <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
                         </tr>
                      </table>
               </td>
             </tr>
        </table>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 2, cell 1</td>
<td>row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>
</table></div>
    <button onclick="geberateCsv(tableContainer)">Save to CSV</button>
```

---

---

The View Model : abcd.ts

```
tableContainer: HtmlElement;

GenerateCsv(control)
{
   var tableText = control.innerHtml;
   console.log(tableText);
}
```

---

The div and its HTML content is being passed and retrieved properly. I Need help to do the following:

1. how to pass the html content (string) to a different page (possibly to a variable of its view-model) . (Open the new page in a new window)
2. then add it as inner HTML of a div on the new page
3. The html content has to be added before page load, so that
   we can change the content  disposition for the page to save it..

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does aurelia have to do with anything? What do you mean by ‘change the content disposition’? Are you working client side or server side? Why would you want to send an entire table instead of just the data?

Comment: @Kokodoko:
 What does aurelia have to do with anything? Aurelia is the JS framework we are using and have to abide by its restrictions. The passing of ref element etc is the aurelia way of referencing the HTML Element from the typescript file, we dont do a Document.GetElementByID etc ...

What do you mean by ‘change the content disposition’?
Content-Disposition is a way in standard html to mark a file (even a html ) to be downloaded to the client machine.. read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Comment: Why would you want to send an entire table instead of just the data?
The data comes from multiple sources and through multiple nested templates. they all get assimilated in the div, so its much easier to just grab the html table and convert it into a csv.. since it is already in the form of columns and rows.. an old asp trick... 
But the moot question here is how do I pass data to another page or its view-model by opening a new window.. and then to bind the data inside it

Comment: In a Single Page client-side app you generally don’t switch between HTML pages, instead you store data in your state and you use data binding to display data (for example, in a table). There is no need to get data back out of the HTML. If you want to transfer data between HTML pages you will need some kind of server.

Comment: It is a utility page and will have to be out of the SPA framework since it will be used to save it as a local file. Anyways if I understand you correct, I can do it this way, save the data to a localstorage and open the other html file... Onload of that HTML retrieve the data from the localstorage and bind it to the appropriate div and display... is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you could use localStorage to persist data between html pages. You could store your data as json. (using JSON.stringify). The other html page can read that string back in, and use JSON.parse before binding it to the html table.